# to set heap memory free is not working as it is supposed to be in C

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I have this code snippet to understand the memory management function `void free(void*)` in C. What I know about `free` function is that it will deallocate the memory that is managed by a pointer. I want to see **what will happen after a block of memory is set free** and **whether the pointer associated is still accessible to that block of memory**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_SIZE 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char originalChar [] = "123456789";
    char *myChar = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * STR_SIZE);
    if (!myChar) {
        printf("allocation failed!");

        exit(1);
    }
    char *isOk = strncpy(myChar, originalChar, STR_SIZE*sizeof(char));
    if(!isOk) exit(1);

    char *myCharCopy = myChar;
    printf("oC = %d, mCC = %d; mC = %d\n", originalChar, myCharCopy, myChar);
    printf("The strings = %s\n", myChar);
    printf("The strings = %s\n", myCharCopy);
    free(myChar);
    printf("----- free happened here -----\n");
    // myChar = NULL;
    printf("oC = %d, mCC = %d; mC = %d\n", originalChar, myCharCopy, myChar);
    printf("The strings = %s\n", myChar);
    printf("The strings = %s\n", myCharCopy);

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I got those results from its output.

```
    oC = 1482066590, mCC = 826278544; mC = 826278544
    The strings = 123456789
    The strings = 123456789
    ----- free happened here -----
    oC = 1482066590, mCC = 826278544; mC = 826278544
    The strings = 123456789
    The strings = 123456789
```

This result makes very little sense to me. Because `free` function is supposed to set free the block of memory but it is **NOT** from the result. What on earth happened here? Besides, it seems the pointer associated with the memory on heap is still accessible to that **freed** memory. Why this will happen since it is freed?

Comment: C does not support OOP. So there are no managed pointers, etc. And there is no information gained invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: And do not not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. No offence, but well-meant advice: before trying to exploit UB, you should get the basics right.

Comment: Thank you. I just saw someone who did `(char*) malloc(...)`, and I don't know if this is a mistake. @Olaf

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: It is required in C++, but in C it should be avoided (see @SouravGhosh 's comment). Also `sizeof(char)` is defined to yield `1` it is nonsense to use it.

Answer (score 3):

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §7.22.3.3, *The `free` function*

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation.[..]

It does not mandate that the pointer would be set to NULL (or anything else, for that matter). `free()`-ing is just an indication to the OS that the allocated memory can be reclaimed and reissued, as and when required.

Accessing `free()`-d memory is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, once `free()` is called, you should not be accessing the pointer anymore.

For this very reason, it is often considered a good practice to set the `free()`-d pointer to NULL immediately after the call to `free()` so that to avoid any unintended access to already freed memory.

---

That said,

```
 printf("oC = %d, mCC = %d; mC = %d\n", originalChar, myCharCopy, myChar);
```

also invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `%d` is to print an `int`, not a pointer (or string, for that matter). In case you want to print the address, you may want to use

```
 printf("oC = %p, mCC = %p; mC = %p\n", (void*)originalChar, (void*)myCharCopy, (void*)myChar);
```

Comment: I saw people set `free()`-d pointer to `NULL`. Thank you. I was a little frustrated about those idioms though -- like to set it NULL after `free()`. Need to get used to it when learning it.

Comment: I still met memory leaks even though I set `myChar` and `myCharCopy` to `NULL`. Why it happened? @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @Life memory leak? Where? BTW you did `free()` __and__ after that set it to NULL, right?

Comment: Yes. I did it like `free(myChar);
 myChar = NULL;
 myCharCopy = NULL;`

Comment: @Life so where do you get a leak then?

Comment: From `valgrind --leak-check=yes ./myFile`, I saw the leak. @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: I don't mean to bother you. But may I ask about those complaints from `valgrind`:  `possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks ==14466==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks ==14466== suppressed: 24,238 bytes in 187 blocks`  @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100412/discussion-between-life-and-sourav-ghosh).

Answer (score 2):

Per the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **7.22.3.3 The `free` function**
>
> ...
>
> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  If `ptr`
>   is a null pointer, no action occurs.  Otherwise, if the argument does
>   not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function,
>   or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc` ,  the behavior is undefined.

But now your code accesses the memory, which invokes undefined behavior, per the C Standard again:

> **J.2  Undefined behavior**
>
> 1      The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to
>   the `free` or `realloc` function is used (7.22.3).

Including appearing to "work".

Comment: Ok. "Undefined behavior" is really hard to understand but I should get used to it. In addition, since `myChar` is freed, what will happen to `myCharCopy`, the one who points to the same piece of memory. Will it be a dangling pointer?

Comment: @Life *what will happen to myCharCopy, the one who points to the same piece of memory. Will it be a dangling pointer?*  It will indeed be a dangling pointer.  Using memory after it's freed is a common bug.

Comment: Since this is a dangling pointer, do we need to set it to `NULL` too?  Or we also need to `free()` it? @Andrew Henle

Comment: @Life *Since this is a dangling pointer, do we need to set it to `NULL` too?* You don't *need* to - it's your code.  It depends on what you want to do.  If the variable is about to go out of scope because it's a local variable for a function that's returning, there'd be no need to set it to NULL.  *Or we also need to `free()` it?*  No, you shouldn't `free()` it.  You can only use `free()` **once** on a pointer value you get from a call to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc.  Doing otherwise is undefined behavior - that usually manifests itself as unexplained crashes later in execution.